# Is it possible to add keypad entry in vehicles that were not designed to have it

Tags: locks, electronics

I have a very old car -  a 1993 - and the power locks simply by putting the actuators in a series circuit that is energized by routing through the switches.

Is there any way to add a keypad entry (not like a remote keypad, but a pad on the car itself) to this system?  I have a habit of swimming in the river, and that's not a great place to loose one's keys.

Comment: Could you do it? Sure, but at what expense? A lot of Ford vehicles have key pads on them for just such an occasion. The thing about it is, how would you go about transplanting one from a Ford to your vehicle. I'm not sure of the systems it uses, but would assume it has something to do with the Body Control Module (BCM - or whatever Ford calls it). I'm not aware of anything available from the aftermarket, but then again, I lead a sheltered life.

Comment: Hmm, could I use some transistors and a microcontroller?  I have the electronics skill to hook it up BUT transistors can fail hot so I'm not sure if it's a grand idea....I would really have to run some wires probably outside of the doors to isolate the device?

Comment: When you say "outside", I'm not sure what you mean. These devices are put into the doors (usually by the handle). I'd have to assume they run a wire from these device pads back through the wire loom of the door, which goes through the door jam and into the under dash portion of the cabin. The BCM is usually under the dash somewhere.

Comment: This wouldn't have a BCM; it's a super super simple circuit with switches in it.  Thus, a solid-state switch would probably cut it.  However, this would have to be outside of a door (dash?) so it doesn't touch anything in case the transistors fail hot (I've seen it happen.)

Comment: A friend had a '91 Camaro with a keypad for the alarm. It wouldn't start the car, but it would kill the engine after a couple of minutes if the code wasn't entered. That was circa 1996.

Answer (score 1):

There are some keypad locks available on the web - those who sell, if you are handy you could re-engineer the output to drive your existing system.

That may be an interesting project, but you could also consider one of those magnetic "key keepers" and put your key in there and hide it under a wing while swimming. Of course you could attach it to the doberman's collar - it should be safe...